# SAS - reduce nb of rows with ranking

Tags: sas, case, rank

I am currently working on a dataset in SAS like this:

people - word - date - rank

A - bla - 01/01/2017 - 1

A - bla - 02/01/2017 - 2

A - test - 03/01/2017 - 3

B - bla - 01/01/2017 - 1

B - test - 09/01/2017 - 2

C - bla - 03/01/2017 - 1

C - test - 05/01/2017 - 2

C - test - 07/01/2017 - 3

C - sas - 08/01/2017 - 4

And I would like to transform it like this :

people - word - rank

A -------- bla ----- 1

A -------- test ----- 2

B -------- bla ----- 1

B -------- test ----- 2

C -------- bla ----- 1

C -------- test ----- 2

C -------- sas ----- 3

The rank is in function of the date, group by people.

I tried to use the **lag function**, but also syntaxes with **case when** (it works but I have to do this for every case and I have a maximum rank of 94... Not really easy !)

So I did not find a great way to have the last table.

Can you help me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post your sample data as text within your question, not as images.

Comment: I have changed my comment :) Is it better ?

Comment: Please describe the logic of your transformation, and add the code you have tried.

Comment: What is the meaning of maximum rank of 94?  Does that mean you want a maximum of 94 observations (i.e. distinct values of WORD) for each value of PEOPLE?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst posting your attempted code is good protocol on this site, I don't think it would help here as `lag` and `case when` are not the way to go.

Essentially you are trying to remove duplicate entries of word and rebase your rank column.  You can achieve this in a single dataset, taking advantage of `first.` processing, which is available when a `by` statement is used.

For the rank, the easiest way is to completely rebuild it from scratch as the data step moves through the records.

```
data have;
input people $ word $ date :ddmmyy10. rank;
format date ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
A  bla  01/01/2017  1
A  bla  02/01/2017  2
A  test  03/01/2017  3
B  bla  01/01/2017  1
B  test  09/01/2017  2
C  bla  03/01/2017  1
C  test  05/01/2017  2
C  test  07/01/2017  3
C  sas  08/01/2017  4
;
run;

data want;
set have (drop=rank date); /* remove rank as being rebuilt; date not required */
by people word notsorted; /* enable first. processing; notsorted option required as data not sorted by people and word */
if first.people then rank=0; /* reset rank when people value changes */
if first.word then do;
    rank+1; /* increment rank by 1 for the first word (will ignore subsesquent duplicates) */
    output; /* output row */
end;
run;
```